# Would the amino acid profile of lab-grown human meat perfectly match the dietary nutritional amino acid requirements for humans?

Tags: proteins, nutrition, amino-acids

Whey protein is the food which has the most ideal (yet not perfect) amino acid profile for humans, whereas gelatin for example has a very poor and incomplete amino acid profile for humans. Would human meat grown in a lab such as they are working on with the [meat alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultured_meat) match our amino acid requirements perfectly since it is actually human tissue?

UPDATE: I was not aware of any hazards that could be involved with consuming human tissues, so I am expanding the question to involve if there is any way to produce human meat safely in a laboratory setting.

Comment: I like the thinking behind this question, obviously human cell lines would not be viable for the numerous safety concerns but I guess it may be theoretically possible to engineer a synthetic tissue from another lineage that matches our exact nutritional requirements?

Comment: @JEJS What would the safety concerns be against consuming lab grown human tissues?

Comment: @wdbwdb1 disease vectors for a start, cooking does not destroy all infectious agents, by definition anything that spreads in humans vat grown cells can infect human cells thus posing a risk to the consumer. this is also why eating great apes is a very big risk.

Comment: @wdbwdb1 In addition to John's comments. Cannibalism is also a source for prion disease such as Bovine Spongiform Encephalopathy (BSE) a.k.a Mad Cow Disease and Creutzfeldt-Jakob Disease (CJD) among humans. An interesting case study is Kuru among the native population of Papua New Guinea from funerary cannibalism - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuru_(disease)

Comment: I was not aware of any hazards that could be involved with consuming human tissues, so I am expanding the question to involve if there is any way to produce human meat safely in a laboratory setting.

Comment: I'm not an expert in nutrition, but I wouldn't necessarily expect human meat alone to exactly match human dietary amino acid requirements, at least not in the exact same abundances in which they are required. Many amino acids (including essential ones) are heavily involved in metabolic activities that have little to do with muscle tissue, like synthesis of hormones or neurotransmitters, so you wouldn't necessarily expect the concentration in muscle to match the dietary needs of a human perfectly.